# [Angular][WebComponent][lifecycle] Can you prevent rendering before multiples properties are set?

Tags: angular, logic, web-component, lifecycle

I'm using a webcomponent to generate some charts. This webcomponent is taking two properties as input for rendering said chart : data and categorie.

showeData and showedCategories are objects mapped together through a common ID by the logic in the webcomponent.

[image: Template WebComponent]

Datapoints and categories can change with graph unit which trigger a treatment to provide correct new data and categories.

[image: onUnitChange setter function]

My problem is that when categories stay the same but data changes, it maps the two correctly, but when data AND categories both change, then webcomponent rerender with first updated prop, throwing an error since data and categories are not correctly mapped. Then when second prop is updated too, it maps the two correctly and display the graph as expected.

How can I bypass this behavior so that component render only when both props are correctly set ? Is there even a way without touching at the webcomponent sources ?

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: Can you provide definition for `wc-chart-line` web component?

Comment: @HarshalPatil well I could change the inner working of the wc-chart-line to have only one prop and then separate data and categories but it better not touch our lib and only work on the angular implementation

Comment: As far as I can see, when you wrap custom component within web component, the properties `data` and `categories` become properties with getter and setter pair. From the `set` function, the render is getting called again and again. Ideally, the library should wrap the changes and wait `nextTick` or `eventloop` cycle before applying those changes to handle this situation.